# Jest + React - match property not set

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am writing some test in Jest for my React application. I have on component that looks at this property "**props.match.params.messageId**" and when I set and render it in my test I see the "match" property getting overridden.

Normally my code passes this through:
.

```
history.push({ pathname: `/path/${myMessageId}` })
```

My test script:

```html
import React from 'react'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import {render, screen, waitFor} from "@testing-library/react";
import EditPost from "../../../src/components/myPostPage";
import {BrowserRouter, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

const locationImpl = {
    state: {},
    pathname:"/testpath1"
};

const myStores_SelectorImpl = {
    UserProfileStore: { data: { data: "d1test" } },
    MessagesStore: { data: [
            {
                "_id": "123"
            }
    ]}
}

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
        useHistory: jest.fn(),
        useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            pathname: '/testpath2',
            search: '',
            hash: '',
            state: {},
            key: '5nvxpbdafa',
        }),
    }
});
jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
        useSelector: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            state: {data: []}
        }),
        useDispatch: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(jest.fn())
    }
});

window.scrollTo = jest.fn();


describe('Render Edit Post Page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        useSelector.mockImplementation((callback) => callback(myStores_SelectorImpl));
        useLocation.mockImplementation(() => locationImpl)
        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <EditPost
                    test={"123"}
                    match={{params: {messageId: 123}}}
                />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    })
    
    afterEach(() => {
        useSelector.mockClear()
        useLocation.mockClear()
    })

    it('should render the Edit Post Page on the given message', async () => {
        expect(screen).toBeDefined()
        const title = screen.queryByText("Title");
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(title).toBeInTheDocument()
        })
    })
})
```

No matter what I do, the match prop is always:

> "match":{"path":"/","url":"/","params":{},"isExact":true}

Edit 1: And btw the rendered component is using 'withRouter'  from react-router-dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This StackOverflow post had the fix for my issue.

I couldn't get it to work with a BrowserRouter and instead had to use MemoryRouter.

[How to use MemoryRouter in order to test useParams call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801455/how-to-use-memoryrouter-in-order-to-test-useparams-call)